# Unable to resolve module remote-redux-devtools

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-devtools

I'm about to set up remote debugging for a react-native app. I've added `remote-redux-devtools` module and also imported it. Does anyone know why am I getting the following error:
`UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module remote-redux-devtools from /Users/.../src/store/createStore.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:....`

It is in the `node_modules` directory (`node_modules/remote-redux-devtools`).

Comment: How're you importing it?

Comment: You might need to restart the packager.. did u do it?

Comment: Silly mistake, this one fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also do not need a module for this. Wherever you create your store define a `composeEnhancers` function and apply it to your middleware:

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
  ...reducers,
  ...initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    ...middleware
  )
)
```